# Gray Xs affecting one network folder

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

**Preface:** I realize this has been posted a few times within TechNet and other forums, but everything references either file sync or NTFS permissions, both which do not seem to be the issue unless I am missing something completely obvious or not understanding a setting. I've also checked for anything GPO-related and nothing I see is stands out at this point.

**Issue:** One of our file shares will randomly show offline (red X under Explorer and the subfolders in said folder will have gray X). This is only affecting one folder, and it will randomly ripple across computers of those accessing it, so I will assume it's safe to rule out the local machine at this point. I was able to get a KLIST output while the issue was and was not occurring, but I don't see any difference. Happens between a mix of Windows 7 and Windows 10, both x64, laptops and desktops, wired or wireless, users are not working remotely.

As mentioned earlier, the issue is inconsistent, but it is only happening in the CAD department, and I know some of the files they store on the network can be quite large (50GB+ .dwg files are not unheard of) so most folders may be very large so I think that may be a factor, but when the issue occurs it will not affect all folders so maybe not.

Let me know if I can provide any additional information and I'll be glad to do so, just completely lost at this point.

Comment: You map your drive how ? gpp, script, etc... A network connection error will cause the X, but I often workaround with a GPP in update mode, it it remove the X when the gpo refresh

Comment: Scripts were used for drive mapping. So basically this is just something Microsoft has never fixed and expects people to use work-arounds?

Comment: Also, to be clear, I've seen the red X many times but I've never seen the gray X on subfolders of the affected drive.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of Client session timeout, Offline file timeout, Idle Connection Timer seems to have helped in this situation:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2013/03/19/cifs-and-smb-timeouts-in-windows/